# Suppose all you knew about an argument was that on one valuation all its atoms are true and its conclusion is false

Tags: logic

This is the classic definition of an invalid argument right?

Comment: Sure, it is the classic definition of an invalid argument. But that does not necessarily mean it is a bad argument; the argument could be a heuristic that is useful under most circumstances, and failing in a few. When it comes to the real world, people mostly think in terms of heuristics like that, which are formally invalid but practically useful and point towards the truth in *most* cases.

Comment: @causative I understand that this does not mean it is a bad argument. But it has to mean it is an invalid argument right. Because I can't see how it will be valid when the above has happened. Or is it the case that it could be valid or invalid?

Comment: You're right, it is invalid. When you use the terms 'valuation' and 'atoms' you limit yourself to propositional logic. More generally, an argument is invalid if there is an *interpretation* under which all the premises are true and the conclusion false. This is the model-theoretic, or Tarskian, account of validity.